# What is the proper syntax of an SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql

Overview: I have a simple query that is trying to retrieve all records where the SENTIMENT column = Negative. However, the where clause is expecting a column name, and will not take a string.

Background Info: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and browsing a table. I wrote the following query -
`SELECT TOP (1000) [VARNAME], [SENTIMENT], [VALUE] FROM my_table WHERE [SENTIMENT] = "Negative";`

This results in the error - `"Invalid column name 'Negative'`

The query DOES run if I instead write

`SELECT TOP (1000) [VARNAME], [SENTIMENT], [VALUE] FROM my_table WHERE [SENTIMENT] = [SENTIMENT];`

But obviously that's a useless query and not what I need.

Question: It's unclear to me as to why this WHERE clause will not take a string as its parameter and instead requires a column name instead.  What's wrong with my syntax here?

Comment: Use single quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Requires single quotes for string operators

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [VARNAME], [SENTIMENT], [VALUE] FROM my_table WHERE [SENTIMENT] = 'Negative';
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in MSSQL use simple quotes, not double quotes. Double quotes are meant for column names.

Try :

SELECT TOP (1000) [VARNAME], [SENTIMENT], [VALUE] FROM my_table WHERE [SENTIMENT] = 'Negative';

IT does work using a ORM because it will add the single quotes for you :)